# Convert unicode to an int or str in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

So I am storing some data that I have scraped from a website. A piece of that data is a number, thats type is unicode and I want to convert it into an int or a str and then into an int so I can add them together. 
I am using python 2.7 and the unicode is u'11:33:52'
How can I turn it into an int

Comment: Do you want to return 3 different integers?  11:33:52 is not an integer as a whole.  Normally you can just convert a str/unicode to an integer by calling `int('123')`.  But in you're case that will raise an exception.

Comment: You'll have to be clearer as to what you expect the output to be here. `int()` doesn't much care if it is a `str` or `unicode` object you pass in, no need to convert to `str` first just for that.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I was pulling the time from the webpage that I am scrapping, just as a test since the website is not currently displaying the object that the script is intended for. The object that I am targeting is a number that will be a float when the site is actually displaying it. So just calling int on the float that will be in unicode will return it as an int?

Comment: If you want to convert the Unicode to a float in Python in order to perform math calcs on it you would call float() not int().

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

a = u'11:33:52'

b = time.strptime(a, "%H:%M:%S")

print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", b))

>> 11:33:52
```

Use `strptime` to get it into proper format then `strftime` will give you the time.

This method will also work in case you get month/day/year format. In that case change `"%H:%M:%S"` to `"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"`